# AngularJS directive wait until templates rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to wrap the SharePoint People Picker in an AngularJS directive. In order to initialise a people picker I need to place a div on the page, give it an ID and pass that ID into a SharePoint function.

I have this working with a basic directive like this:

```
<sp-people-picker id="test"></sp-people-picker>
```

But I wish for the directive to be useable anywhere, including in a repeating section:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataset">
    <sp-people-picker id="test-{{ $index }}"></sp-people-picker>
</div>
```

This fails. I stepped through the code to see what was going wrong and found that while I was happily calling the SharePoint people picker function with "test-0" it was failing to find the element. `document.getElementById("test-0")` returned null. The reason for this is that my div still had the id "test-{{ $index }}" and only gets "test-0" AFTER my directive has compiled.

How can I make sure my directive runs after the {{ }} has been rendered?

(Not tagging with SharePoint as the SharePoint stuff is just the context, it's not actually relevant to the issue I'm trying to solve)

Comment: I have temporarily got this working using setTimeout with 1ms to delay my code. I'd rather a nicer method but this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `attrs.$observe` inside your directive link function, that will act as the same as like $watch, the difference is it can watch on the `{{}}` interpolation directive, Your link function will look like below. It call function whenever interpolation directive gets evaluated.

**Directive**(Link Function)

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    attrs.$observe(attrs.id, function(newVal, oldVal){
        //here you can get new value & `{{}}` is evaluated.
    });
}
```